# Como puedo hacer un inner join entre 3 tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer un inner join entre 3 tablas.

Esto tienen mis tablas:

APPX_employee (id, firstname, lastname, department_id, salary, educationlevel_id)

APPX_department (id, department_name, department_city)

APPX_educationlevel (id, description)

Estoy tratando de obtener el apellido y descripcion educacional de los empleados que trabajan en un departamento donde la suma de los salarios es mayor a 250000.

La consulta que realicé es la siguiente:

```
SELECT `lastname`, `description` FROM APPX_employee AS emp 
INNER JOIN APPX_department AS dep
ON emp.department_id = dep.id

INNER JOIN APPX_educationlevel AS edu 
ON emp.educationlevel_id = edu.id

 WHERE emp.salary>250000;
```

Pero por alguna razon no me devuelve ningun registro cuando si me los tendría que devolver.

Alguien sabe que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Agrega lo que obtienes como resultado, cuales son los campos que te salen como resultado?

Comment: Me devuelve no records returned. Como que ningún registro coincide con lo que le estoy pasando cuando en realidad si.

Comment: Proba usar `LEFT JOIN`, a lo mejor no tenes datos en alguna de las otras tablas.

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero Realicé una edicion en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez no te presenta información porque no estas especificando los campos que necesitas realmente.

Estas haciendo un `` SELECT `lastname`, `description` ``  cuando realmente estas haciendo uso de 3 tablas diferentes, entonces no se sabe de que tabla le vas a presentar los datos.

Asegúrate de ponerle el prefijo de la tabla para que le indiques al motor de mysql que estas haciendo referencia a tal tabla y de usar **JOIN** para obtener toda la información.

Algo como:

```
SELECT emp.lastname, edu.description FROM APPX_employee AS emp 
JOIN APPX_department AS dep
ON emp.department_id = dep.id

JOIN APPX_educationlevel AS edu 
ON emp.educationlevel_id = edu.id

WHERE emp.salary>250000;
```

Comment: Perdon estaba haciendo mal lo que se me pedía. Ahora paso a editar la pregunta. No eran los empleados que tienen un sueldo mayor a 250000 sino donde la suma de sueldos dentro de un mismo departamento es mayor a 250000

Answer (score 2):

Pues como me han enseñado a mi yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
USE prueba; # Usa la bd de tus 3 tablas
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sumSueldo $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE sumSueldo()
BEGIN
    DECLARE sueldo FLOAT; # Declaramos una variable

    # Guardamos el valor del salario en el into en la variable sueldo anteriormente declarada
    SELECT SUM(salary) into sueldo FROM APPX_employee,APPX_department,APPX_educationlevel
    WHERE APPX_employee.id=APPX_department.id AND APPX_department.id=APPX_educationlevel.id;
    
    # Hacemos ya la consulta con la variable sueldo anteriormente declarada
    SELECT lastname,description FROM APPX_employee,APPX_department,APPX_educationlevel
    WHERE APPX_employee.id=APPX_department.id AND APPX_department.id=APPX_educationlevel.id AND 
    sueldo>250000;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
call sumSueldo(); # Esto llamas al procedimiento parecido a una function
```

Nosotros no usamos los inner join nosotros unimos la tablas con el nombre la tabla y con lo que se empareja en este caso yo entiendo que el id, hacemos un primer select con el cual guardamos los sueldos de los empleados de los distintos departamentos, y luego a traves de la variable sueldo hacemos la comprobación.

Si lo quieres llamar debes usar `call sumSueldo();` y cada vez que cierre el terminal lo debes ejecutar de nuevo esto. Yo he realizado una prueba y me funciona.

Saludos espero que te haya servido.